# Catching and halting on syntax exceptions during parsing with HXT

Tags: haskell, hxt

Suppose an XML based language where the node attribute `animal` is illegal. Consider:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows, RankNTypes #-}
module Lib ( parseXml ) where
import Control.Arrow
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

parseXml = runLA (xread >>> isElem >>> myParser) content
  where
    content = unlines
      [ "<pet animal='cat'>felix</pet>"
      , "<pet>milo</pet>"
      , "<pet animal='rat'>tom</pet>" ]

myParser :: (ArrowXml a) => a XmlTree [String]
myParser =  proc xml -> do
  x <- isElem -< xml
  pets <- (getText <<< getChildren <<< neg (hasAttr "animal")) >. id -< x
  returnA -< pets
```

The result of evaluating `parseXml` is:

```
parseXml
[[],["milo"],[]]
```

Which is not what is intended. The parser has silently ignored the 1st and 3rd XML nodes since they do not conform to the `myParser`, specifically `neg (hasAttr "animal")`, but I'd like the behaviour to not silently ignore them, but instead halt parsing at the 1st XML node.

How can I change this code such that HXT throw an error if it ever encounters our syntax violation that an XML node can **never** have an "animal" attribute? That is, when attempting to parse the 1st XML node it returns a `Left` value e.g.

```
parseXml
Left (ParseError "'animal' attribute is not permitted")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`err`](http://www.fh-wedel.de/~si/HXmlToolbox/hdoc/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlArrow.html#v:err) and its neighbors with [`when`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-8.3.1/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowIf.html).

Comment: How exactly? I've modified the parser to be `(getText <<< getChildren <<< neg (hasAttr "animal") <<< when (fatal "'animal' attribute is not permitted") (hasAttr "animal"))`, but I still get `[[],["milo"],[]]` when evaluating `parseXml`.